# iwlwifi Wifi Microcode SW error detected (Ubuntu 18.04 x64)

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, iwlwifi, firmware

I can connect to my home wifi network. However, internet browsing speed is just very slow.

Interesting fact is, I can connect to the same network from my Windows machine and I don't see any problems with speed. It seems this Ubuntu specific issue.

My Ubuntu laptop has Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168. I did some research online, found that this issue could be related to linux-firmware. I am using v29.1044073957.0.

But still not sure what the problem is.

I ran wireless-info tool which generated this report.

Report shows some errors:-

```
[  213.909410] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Microcode SW error detected.  Restarting 0x2000000.
[  213.909528] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[  213.909530] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Status: 0x00000100, count: 6
[  213.909532] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 29.1044073957.0
[  213.909534] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000084 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UNKNOWN       
[  213.909535] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00800634 | trm_hw_status0
[  213.909537] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[  213.909538] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00043D54 | branchlink2
[  213.909539] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0004AFA6 | interruptlink1
[  213.909541] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00024558 | interruptlink2
[  213.909542] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | data1
[  213.909544] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000080 | data2
[  213.909545] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x07030000 | data3
[  213.909547] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0E80A919 | beacon time
[  213.909548] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xF5FB26E5 | tsf low
[  213.909549] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000033 | tsf hi
[  213.909551] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[  213.909552] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00C099B8 | time gp2
[  213.909554] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[  213.909555] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000001D | uCode version major
[  213.909557] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x3E3B4DE5 | uCode version minor
[  213.909558] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000220 | hw version
[  213.909559] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00C89200 | board version
[  213.909561] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0ABD001C | hcmd
[  213.909562] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xA4022002 | isr0
[  213.909564] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[  213.909565] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000000A | isr2
[  213.909566] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x004028C5 | isr3
[  213.909568] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[  213.909569] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0503001C | last cmd Id
[  213.909571] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[  213.909572] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000080 | l2p_control
[  213.909573] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00012030 | l2p_duration
[  213.909575] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000003F | l2p_mhvalid
[  213.909576] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000080 | l2p_addr_match
[  213.909578] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000007 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[  213.909579] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x03041751 | timestamp
[  213.909580] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00342028 | flow_handler
```

Full Report:

I uploaded it [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bzLumgeDeJvEtv71M5ONrzu7XQoGdJ8K)

**Output of *sudo dpkg -s linux-firmware***

```
Package: linux-firmware
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: misc
Installed-Size: 271097
Maintainer: Ubuntu Kernel Team <kernel-team@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Multi-Arch: foreign
Version: 1.173.1
Replaces: atmel-firmware, linux-firmware-snapdragon (<= 1.2-0ubuntu1), linux-restricted-common
Provides: atmel-firmware
Breaks: linux-firmware-snapdragon (<= 1.2-0ubuntu1)
Conflicts: atmel-firmware
Description: Firmware for Linux kernel drivers
 This package provides firmware used by Linux kernel drivers.
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: sudo dpkg -s linux-firmware` We wish your router wasn't using WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and the very insecure TKIP.

Comment: @chili555 please check.

Comment: I have tried all possible combinations, mixed mode, TKIP, AES, etc.. That change nothing, speed remains slow.

Comment: WPA2-AES and a fixed channel is what I suggest. Is the firmware corrupted? `md5sum /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode` xxe83e?? Your linux-firmware package is the latest.

Comment: firmware file is not corrrupted. checksum matches. It is xxe83e. I don't know what is the problem here? any further trouble-shooting you suggest?

Comment: We might try renaming the -29 file so that an earlier firmware file loads and see if it helps. Do you need an explicit step-by-step?

Comment: @chili555 My wifi is working fine since today morning. I didn't do anything. I think somewhere the new update fixed the problem. Out of curiosity, I just looked at which updates were installed today morning. No mention of firmware in the list however there is intel-microcode:amd64 3.20180425.1~ubuntu0.18.04.1 in that list. Looks like that was it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to create a configuration file, like so:

```bash
echo "options cfg80211 cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz=Y" > /etc/modprobe.d/cfg80211.conf
```

And reboot.

[This disables 40mHz support](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/module-parameters#ieee80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz1) from the 2.4GHz band in the 802.11 *sub*system (which is why it's an option for `cfg80211` and not your wifi adapter's driver).

Comment: I wanted to confirm this worked with Intel Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210 (aka 7265D where -29 is indeed the latest version at time of writing as you can see [here](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#d_3165_and_3168_support)) on (L)ubuntu 18.04 using firmware 29.1044073957.0 and linux-firmware 1.173.21.

Answer (score 1):

Had similar issues with Wi-Fi Link 5100.
The firmware (reliably) hangs when performing `iperf3` transmit tests.
The solution was to disable TX aggregation.

`options iwlwifi 11n_disable=2`

Other answers on the internet suggest using `11n_disable=1` but that disables 802.11n entirely.